# Why does my code not display the total?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drop-down-menu

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>List Totals</h2>

<p>Display myList Total:</p>

<p id="total"></p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select id = "myList">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
      </select>
<p></p>      
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select id = "myList2">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
      </select>

</form>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myList"+"myList2");
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = x;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry, this is my first attempt at making a HTML/JS form by using two drop-down menus and adding the values for a total. It seems to not let me have a total. What am I doing wrong? Thanks you all!

Comment: Looks like you're trying to get element "myListmyList2" rather than getting both elements and adding them. Look at where your parentheses are in your first line of the script.

Comment: Also, for getting the value of the selected option, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select id = "myList" onchange="recalc()">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
      </select>
<p></p>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select id = "myList2" onchange="recalc()">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
      </select>

</form>

<script>
function recalc() {
var x =   parseInt(document.getElementById("myList").value)
        + parseInt(document.getElementById("myList2").value);
    console.log( x , ' x ');
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, you have not attached any event to your elements.
- `getElementById` expected ID of the element hence your syntax is invalid.
- Use `ternary-operator` or `Number` to convert string to number as `value` property returns string hence it would be concatenated not added.

```js
var select1 = document.getElementById("myList");
var select2 = document.getElementById("myList2");

select1.onchange = manipulate;
select2.onchange = manipulate;

function manipulate() {
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = +select1.value + +select2.value;
}
```

```html
<h2>List Totals</h2>
<p>Display myList Total:</p>
<p id="total"></p>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select id="myList">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
      </select>
  <p></p>
</form>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select id="myList2">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
      </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myList"+"myList2");
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = x;
```

to this:

```
var x1 = document.getElementById("myList");
var x2 = document.getElementById("myList2");
var value1 = x1.options[x1.selectedIndex].text;
var value2 = x2.options[x2.selectedIndex].text;
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = value1 + value2;
```

And add in HTML tag with id="total". For example, so:

```
<span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!